# Google Identity Toolkit Java library's gitkitClient.getAllUsers() doesn't work correctly

Tags: google-app-engine, google-identity-toolkit

I have been trying to get all the users for my web application (GAE for Java backend) using gitkitClient.getAllUsers(). I'm just getting started with Identity Toolkit and have 10-12 users.

When I call `gitkitClient.getAllUsers()` it doesn't find any user and returns this warning:

```
com.google.identitytoolkit.GitkitClient$1 getNextResults
WARNING: JSONObject["email"] not found.
```

If I call it with a parameter for max results `gitkitClient.getAllUsers(5)`, it returns 5 users correctly. But if I pass 7, it again doesn't find any user, and returns the same warning (as above). I know that I have 10+ users.

If I use `gitkitClient.getUserByEmail("test@example.com")` I can get the users that are not returned in the first 5.

Here's my code sample:

```
Iterator<GitkitUser> allUsers = gitkitClient.getAllUsers();

int count = 0;
if (allUsers != null) {
    while (allUsers.hasNext()) {
        count++;
        GitkitUser gUser = allUsers.next();
        logger.info("" + count + ". User email : " + gUser.getEmail() + " Id : " + gUser.getLocalId());                             
    }   
}
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the iterator like this:
    val userIterator = gitkitClient.getAllUsers();
    while (userIterator.hasNext()) {
      LOG.warning(userIterator.next().getEmail)
    }

I've not been keeping to close an eye on the number of users, but this seems to return ALL of the known users.

B.

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm using. I have added code sample to my original post. Thanks for your help.